# Enviar datos por POST desde un DataTable

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy usando una DataTable creada dinamincamente desde una BD en la cual capturo el evento `onclick` de cual fila fue seleccioanada y recojo sus datos, ahora lo que necesito es que me redireccione a otro archivo php (quiero enviarlos por POST) en el cual se deben capturar los datos enviados y dependiendo de esos datos cargar cierta informacion.

el codigo de js donde capturo los datos es este:

```
$('#Jtabla tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            dato =table.row( this ).data();
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            dato =table.row( this ).data();

            $('<form action="proyectos.php" method="POST">' + 
           '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + dato+ '">' +
           '</form>').submit();

             //intente con esto pero me sale este error en consola
//Form submission canceled because the form is not connected
        }
    } );
```

aqui creeria que se deben enviar por ajax, pero se que el ajax hace la peticion y vuelve, y yo lo que necesito es que lleve los datos alla.
quedo atento, muchas gracias

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax.

Comment: pero el ajax envia hace la peticion y cuando hace la peticion a donde la haria ? y aun mas, cuando vuelve y redirecciono el valor es restablecido, ya te pongo lo que tengo de ajax

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con que va y vuelve, con ajax haces una petición, la misma viaja al servidor y este la procesa y devuelve un response con o sin datos, pero esto no tiene porque afectar la navegación del usuario, a menos que sea un error o mensaje y este contemplado asi por el servior pero esto ya es otro tema.

Comment: Lo que no quita la posibilidad, que desde el servidor php re direcciones al usuario, inclusive con datos, lo cual se usa mucho en el manejo de sesiones. header('Location: /login.php?Message=session+expired');

Comment: Tambien podrias generar un form dinamicamente.

Comment: lo que sucede es que cunado ha  echo la peticion lo redirecciono al mismo archivo y cuando lo redirecciono ya la variable no existe en proyectos.php

Comment: @alanfcm ya lo intente con esto.... $('<form action="proyectos.php" method="POST">' + 
               '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + dato+ '">' +
               '</form>').submit(); pero me sale un error.

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes que conectar la forma primero al documento antes de poder mandarla.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$('#Jtabla tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        dato =table.row( this ).data();
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        dato =table.row( this ).data();

        $('<form action="proyectos.php" method="POST">' + 
       '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + dato+ '">' +
       '</form>').appendTo('body').submit();

    }
} );
```

Comment: gracias Maestro, algun dia como vos.... :) a la final no estana tan lejos de la realidad XD

Comment: de nada, y si, andabas muy cerca y con buenos instintos.