# Cómo enviar valores con AJAX y redireccionar a otra página con el mismo botón

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

estoy tratando de pasar los valores de una pagina a otra con un boton, y a la vez que el mismo boton me direcciones a esa pagina.

mi index.php seria este:

```
    <select name="inc_sem_zon_per" id="inc_sem_zon_per">
       <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
       <option value="CENTRO">CENTRO</option>
       <option value="LIMA">LIMA</option>
       <option value="SUR">SUR</option>                                      
     </select>

   <div >
      <button onclick="actualizar();" onclick="location.href='actualizardatos.php'" >enviar</button>
 </div>
```

luego miraria la javascript funciones.js donde tomara el valor y lo enviare a actualizardatos.php:

```
function actualizar(){
 var parametros={
  "ver": $("#inc_sem_zon_per").val(),
 }
  $.ajax({
  data: parametros,
  url:"actualizardatos.php",
  type:"POST",
});
```

}

y entonces cuando haga el click en el boton me envie a otra pagina y a la vez reciba el valor escogido en el select y lo imprima

```
 <?php

   $ver=$_POST['ver'];
   echo "string ".$ver;
 ?>
```

he tratado de hacerlo de esta manera pero no me sale... ¿como podria desarrollarlo?

Comment: Conteste una pregunta similar ayer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183431/enviar-datos-por-post-desde-un-datatable/183439#183439

Comment: solo se trabajaria con ese codigo? ya que en si es distinto a como lo estaba realizando

Comment: Si lo haces con Ajax, tendrias que redirigir en PHP.  Creo que es mas facil generando un form dinamico.

Comment: claro, pero lo que pasa es que en mi caso estoy pasando el valor de un select, y creo que por eso no lo estoy entendiendo mejor

Comment: Seria exactamente igual, solo que en lugar de agregar un input hidden, agregarias tu select.

Comment: Es muy simple: tienes el método `$.ajax({ //... }).done(function(resp){ // tratas la respuesta });` Si la respuesta es satisfactoria, al tratarla puedes usar el atributo `action` del botón cambiarlo y volverlo a llamar o simplemente usar el método navigate() para redirigir. En otro caso muestras una alerta indicando el fallo. No uses alert() porque los navegadores molestan cuando se invoca varias veces; muestra el mensaje en una capa emergente que se oculte con un botón aceptar.

Comment: Mayúsculas == gritar, edita el título por favor.

Comment: No deberías poner el titulo en mayúsculas

Comment: @alanfcm con respecto a la direccion que comentaste... en mi caso el select, lo tengo dentro de un form, en mi pregunta lo puse sin form para que se entienda, pero como haria si es que el select lo tengo dentro de un form y poder realizar el form dinamico que comentaste?

Answer (score 1):

Si no entiendo mal, lo que necesitás es hacer primero una llamada por ajax, y después redireccionar. Para eso, ajax tiene diferentes eventos: done, success, error, etc. Entonces, por JS, le podés indicar que cuando haya terminado con el pedido de ajax, redireccione a otra página. Para poder pasarle la página con una variable de PHP, si es que lo necesitás, podés pasarla por parámetro en actualizar. Quedaría así:

```
<button onclick="actualizar('actualizardatos.php');">enviar</button>
```

Y el JS:

```
function actualizar(redireccion){
 var parametros={
  "ver": $("#inc_sem_zon_per").val()
 };

 $.ajax({
   data: parametros,
   url:"actualizardatos.php",
   type:"POST",
 }).success(function() {
    window.location.href(redireccion);
  });
}
```

Comment: intente poner tu codigo, pero no me direcciona a la siguiente pagina. en mi caso el JS lo tengo en otra pagina llamada funciones.JS , sera por eso que no da?

Comment: No realmente... deberías poder correr el código desde un archivo separado. Revisé bien la sintaxis y agregué un punto y coma y llave. Fijáte si es eso. Si hay algún error, la consola te debería avisar. Por otra parte, estás seguro de que el llama la función actualizar()?

Comment: si, en tu JS le faltaba una llave,y lo agregue... al momento de dar click no realiza nada el boton. la funcion se llama actualizar() , que crees que pueda ser

Comment: Creo que deberias de verificar con el depurador de Google Chrome si el Ajax se está ejecutando, ahí puedes ver si te manda algun error ya sea en el JS o del lado del Servidor en tu PHP.

Comment: La funcion que yo te pasé es actualizar(redireccion). Si no le pasás el parámetro de la página para redireccionar, no la va a reconocer. Si ponés un console.log al principio de la función, aparece en consola cuando hacés click en el botón?